# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' in ionic 3 app

Tags: gradle, ionic3

[image]

This is my ionic info
And this is the error
[image]

I enter the commands in this sequence
cordova platforms add android
ionic cordova emulate android
and some times ionic cordova run android --device and connect a device with PC.

Answer (score 0):

Installing this plugins `cordova-plugin-androidx` and `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter` will solve this problem:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```